# What is wrong with this JS if Condition test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

this code works fine without the if condition test, where am I going wrong here with the if condition?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("input[name=contest_open]").val() == true) {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function()
  {
       $('#tweets').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
       $.get("/event", { event:$("input[name=event]").val(), }, function(data) {
         console.log(data.success);
         console.log(data.page_link);
         console.log('Succesfully Loaded Data from JSON FORMAT GET');
         $('#tweets').html(data.html);
         $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
       });      
  }, 30000); 
  }
})
```

Comment: Though the code does not describe a lot, try using if ($("input[name=contest_open]").val()) only..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `val` does not return a boolean value. If you are trying to check whether the `value` of `input[name=contest_open]` is not empty, try `val() !== ""` instead.

If you are trying to check whether the value is the string "true", you need to enclose `true` with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

val() will return a string.

Use this if you want to test against "true"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("input[name=contest_open]").val() === "true") {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function()
  {
       $('#tweets').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
       $.get("/event", { event:$("input[name=event]").val(), }, function(data) {
         console.log(data.success);
         console.log(data.page_link);
         console.log('Succesfully Loaded Data from JSON FORMAT GET');
         $('#tweets').html(data.html);
         $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
       });      
  }, 30000); 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for existense, then use :

```
if ($("input[name=contest_open]").val())
```

only.

On the ither hand, if you intend to check the contents reading "true", you can use

```
if ($("input[name=contest_open]").val() == "true")
```

For the simple reason that val() function returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you have `==`, 1 or an object will also evaluate as true. With `===` it will only evaluate as true if it is a boolean true.

Comment: You probably want `=== "true"` since .val() returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you think the value can contain "True" then its better to convert to lowercase.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("input[name=contest_open]").val() == "true") {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function()
  {
       $('#tweets').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
       $.get("/event", { event:$("input[name=event]").val(), }, function(data) {
         console.log(data.success);
         console.log(data.page_link);
         console.log('Succesfully Loaded Data from JSON FORMAT GET');
         $('#tweets').html(data.html);
         $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
       });      
  }, 30000); 
  }
})
```